# Show only the categories added by the specific logged in author

Tags: wordpress

I want to Show only the categories added by the specific logged in author. For example if a user **test** get logged in to his account. he get only the list of categories, which he has added.

**test:** foo, bar

**test2:** cat1, cat2

How I can achieve this task programmatically?

I've done this task for the Posts by using this code:

```
function w3pile_hide_nonvendor_products($query_vars) {
    $query_vars['author'] = get_current_user_id();

    return $query_vars;
}

function w3pile_edit_nonvendors() {
    add_action('request', 'w3pile_hide_nonvendor_products');
}

add_action('load-edit.php', 'w3pile_edit_nonvendors');
```

But this code is not working for taxonomies.

Comment: WordPress doesn't track the user that has created a category...

Comment: @rnevius is there any trick/technique to track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress tracks which user created a post, page, or comment, but not for categories or tags. You'd have to add this tracking in yourself. You probably want to use `update_user_meta()` to track which taxonomy/category IDs the user created. You can get those IDs at the point of creation using:

```
do_action( "create_$taxonomy", $term_id, $tt_id );
```

or

```
do_action( "create_term", $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
```

I'm listing both because you mentioned categories, but you can use these for any taxonomy (categories, tags, custom terms).

Something like this (untested) should work or get you on track:

```
function track_user_category( $term_id, $tt_id ){
    // Get the user id
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // See if user has created categories before
    $categories_created = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'categories_created', true );
    if( empty( $categories_created ) ){
      // This is the first time the user has created a category
      // Create a new array and add the term
      $categories_created = array( $term_id );
    } else {
      // The user has existing categories
      // Add this one to the list
      $categories_created[] = $term_id;
    }
    // Update the user meta with the new category list
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'categories_created', $categories_created );
}
add_action( "create_category", "track_user_category", 10, 2 );
```

**To retrieve the categories later**, you can get the IDs from the user meta and iterate through the array to get the categories. Something like:

```
$categories_created_by_user = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'categories_created', true );

if( !is_array( $categories_created_by_user ) ){
      // The user hasn't created any categories
} else {
    foreach( $categories_created_by_user as $category_id ){
        $cat = get_term( $category_id, 'category' );
        // Now, you have the term object as $cat
        // Do what you need - print the title, get the link, whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: After that How I will limit WordPress to show only logged in user's category?

Comment: Once you've stored them in the user meta, you can call that whenever you want. First, get the ids with get_user_meta. Then, iterate through the array of IDs and get_term( $id, 'category) for each.